# How do I display a alert on a website?

Tags: javascript, alert

I wanted to have a message pop up in the middle of the page of my website when there is a important announcement like the one below. Any ideas of what to use. I tries looking at the code but I have no idea how to get it to work. Any ideas will be appreciated.

[Image (My Idea of how it should look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xeuf.png)

Comment: Well, there's the native `window.alert('message');` But if you want something prettier, I might suggest: https://github.com/robinparisi/tingle

Comment: There's a multitude of ways to do that. Without a clear understanding of what technology your website uses or code samples, there is no way for us to help you.

Comment: It depends on what web framework you use.

Comment: I use New Google Sites. I do not want it be link soandso.com says: then the message. I wanted something just like the picture shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have tagged 'javascript' on this question, so I will show you the most common way to do it completely using javascript.

Use the `alert()` function. The alert function takes one parameter — the text that you want to show. All browsers will present this in a different way. This is really easy to do and is recommended especially if you are just starting.

An example of implementing this on your HTML website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('My message goes here');
</script>
```

If you want to change the way this looks, you will have to use an HTML modal. By using that, you can customize the HTML&CSS to look exactly like the picture you attached.

To get started with that, I recommend you check out W3Schools tutorial on this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp